# properly subtract variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

This is literally the first few functions I've ever written...it works, but I was wondering if there was another more efficient way of limiting variable i to nothing below 0 and nothing above 5 rather than making those extra if statements in each .click().....then again the code is very minimal so maybe this is the most efficient way of limiting a variable?!

```
var i=0;
$(".add").click(function(event){
    if(i < 5) {
        var container = $('div');
        container.append($("<p class='blabla'>blablabla</p>"));
        if(i < 5){i++}
    }
});

$(".delete").click(function(event){
    if(i < 5, i > 0){i--}
    $("div p:last-of-type").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of counting, use a max value you want to control and let jQuery do the rest:

http://jsfiddle.net/3D69b/

```
<a class='add'>Add</a><br/>
<a class='delete'>Del</a>
<div class='add'>AppendToMe</div>
```

Then:

```
var gv_nMax = 5;

$(".add").click(function(event){
    if($("div p").length < gv_nMax) 
    $('div').append($("<p class='blabla'>blablabla</p>"))
});
$(".delete").click(function(event){ $("div p:last-of-type").remove(); });
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I wish you could choose multiple answers but I chose yours since you added to gvee's answer which showed me a new way to do it and you have the least amount of reputation than the guys below...besides the fact that your answer is the shit, lol...thanks again!

Comment: Thanks :). I was on the phone or I would have been faster. Sorry! ;) @gvee's is the closest to mine except abstracting the max value.

Comment: Keep in mind you will want your selectors to be more specific the more complex your page becomes. `div p` will get all p's under a div.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the second check in `if (i<5) i++;` (that block wouldn't have been entered if `i` was 5 or more).

Also, You can just write `if(i > 0) i--;`, because it doesn't matter there whether `i` is more than 5.

[Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/RpN7c/2/)

Answer (score 1):

> making those extra if statements in each `.click()`…

They're necessary and fine. However, you can shorten them a little.

> ```
> ….append($("<p class='" + name + " select'>" + name + "</p>"));
> ```

The [`append` method](http://api.jquery.com/append/) does accept plain HTML strings as well, you don't need to wrap them in a `$()` invocation.

> ```
> if(i < 5) {
>     if(i < 5){i++}
> }
> ```

The inner `if` condition is superfluous. Nothing has changed `i` in between, so you don't need to check again.

> ```
> if(i < 5, i > 0){i--}
> ```

Here you're actually using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which only yields the right operand to take effect in the effect. You probably wanted an [`&&` AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators), but you should not check for `i<5` at all - it won't get outside the range anyway and you don't want to duplicate the upper boundary.

So use

```
var i=0;
$(".add").click(function(event){
    if (i < 5) {
        var container = $('div');
        container.append("<p class='blabla'>blablabla</p>");
        i++;
    }
});
$(".delete").click(function(event){
    if (i > 0) {
        $("div p:last-of-type").remove();
        i--;
    }
});
```

Another approach, without the counter variable `i`, would be to count the existing elements each time:

```
$(".add").click(function(event){
    var container = $('div');
    if (container.find("p").length < 5) {
        container.append("<p class='blabla'>blablabla</p>");
    }
});
$(".delete").click(function(event){
    $("div p:last-of-type").remove(); // if nothing is found nothing is removed anyway
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Bergi you really helped me understand all the parts of the code! I decided to give williambq the answer cause hes got less rep even though your answer is BOSS, hope your not mad...your the shit!

Answer (score 1):

In your example you actually don't need the variable `i` as you can simply count the number of elements.

```
$(".add").click(function () {
    if ($('div').children('p').length < 5) {
        $('div').append('<p>item</p>');
    }
});
```

or

```
$(".add").click(function () {
    if ($('div p').length < 5) {
        $('div').append('<p>item</p>');
    }
});
```

And your remove function doesn't need to check for the number of items at all as the selector just won't find anything to remove.

```
$(".delete").click(function () {
    $('div p:last-of-type').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me this new way! I was looking into length earlier but wasn't sure how it worked....added a new jquery term to my vocabulary I appreciate it! I was gonna give you the answer but williambq expanded on it and has less rep. Anywho thanks again!